# Cant rename a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've tried to rename a column from `row` which is int in my db to `row_number`.
The name of my table is screening_occapancy. I tried this:

`ALTER TABLE  screening_occapancy CHANGE COLUMN row to row_number;`

**The error is:**
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'row to row_number' at line 1.

Comment: You need to provide the full column definition. It's not possible to just change the name.

Comment: Both `row` and `row_number` are reserved words.

Comment: That's the point i've got an assignment from college and my db contains this table with a column named row (which is the full name of the column) how do I overcome this problem?